# Use AJAX to obtain an array from php database query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What I am trying is obtain an array from a php file where I am making a query to a database. This array contains the results of that query.
But I cannot make AJAX work, I am unsure of how to use it. 
It is my php code

```html
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($mysqli -> connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error ('.$mysqli -> connect_errno.') '.$mysqli -> connect_error);
}
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM Coordinates");

$coordinates = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  $coordinates[] = $row["coordinate1"];
print json_encode($coordinates);
$mysqli -> close();
```

I have tried multiples approaches for use AJAX
This is one of them, but not sure what to write in the data parameter

```js
function getData() {
  console.log("working here");
  jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'getInformation.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data: 'coordinates',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
      console.log("working here");
      alert(data[0]);
    },
  });
}
```

And the other one

```js
function getData(){
  var res = new Array();
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#previous").click(function(){
      jQuery.getJSON("getInformation.php", function(data) {
        res[0]=data.$coordinates[0];
        jQuery("#result").html(res[0]);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Which is the correct way of using AJAX?
Also, I am trying of return the array to another method.
How can I do that?
return data[0]?

Comment: For the data prop of your ajax it would be data: { serverSideVariablesName: dataObjectYouArePassing },

Answer (score 0):

```js
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli - > connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error ('.$mysqli - > connect_errno.') '.$mysqli - > connect_error);
}
$result = $mysqli - > query("SELECT * FROM Coordinates");
$coordinates = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  // $coordinates[] = $row["coordinate1"]; // change it like below
  $coordinates[] = array($row["coordinate1"]); 
print json_encode($coordinates);
$mysqli - > close();
```

And after that simply fetch it by name with passing any parameters

In ajax response

**alert(data);**

Comment: Hi, thank you!!
But I keep having problems with the ajax part, if I try to fetch the result without any parameters I have an error, the best result that I have had is fetch all the php document, not the result, but the code in my php document

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to set the content-type header when "echoing" JSON-data:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
.
.
echo json_encode($data);
```

When fetching data I would use the GET-method

```
$.getJSON( "getInformation.php", function( data ) {
    $("#result").html(data.coordinates[0]);
});
```

You can pass the returned data to another method as an argument, or you can set the returned data in a global variable the can be accesses from any method, just remember that the data won't be available before the data is returned from your request

```
var globalVar = "";
$.getJSON( "getInformation.php", function( data ) {
   //$("#result").html(data.coordinates[0]);
    globalVar = data; //OR
    myMethod(data);
});
```